# Run Script from node_modules in a <script> tag without having to call the function separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a simple boilerplate HTML template.

All I want to do is run a simple script which I have installed as an npm package - the script just appends the word "test" into a div with the id of "result":

```
const test = () => {
    $('#result').append('test')
}
```

Currently, the npm package installs fine and works fine by using this script tag:

```
<script src="../node_modules/@MYUSERNAME/testgenerator/id.js"></script>
```

However, this script ONLY runs if I call the function separately in a separate script tag:

```
 <script>test()</script>
```

Is there a way to make the script run WITHOUT having to use this extra script tag with the function call?

I tried adding the call to the original script like so:

```
const test = () => {
    $('#result').append('test')
}

test()
```

But this did nothing.

Is there any way I can get the script to run without having to call it in a separate script tag ?

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="../node_modules/@MYUSERNAME/testgenerator/id.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="result"></div>
    <script>test()</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"But this did nothing."_ - it did not do nothing, it called the function, as to be expected. But of course `$('#result')` will now not _find_ the element, because the function now gets executed before the element event exists. If you want to keep embedding the script into the document _before_ the element you are trying to target - then you need to wrap the function call into a document ready handler.